# My image is not working as background image

Tags: css, url, background, icons, background-image

> In my css i've given url() of img but it is not working as background img when code is executed on browser.
> My HTML is stored in  htdocs->ALUMEET->profile.html
> My CSS is stored in  htdocs->ALUMEET->CSS->profile.css
> My image is stored in htdocs->ALUMEET->images->help2.jpg
> XAMPP is used

> html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Profile</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/profile.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="profilebox">
                <i class="uil uil-bars icon"></i>  
                <i class="uil uil-setting icon"></i>
                <img src="images/profilepic.jpg" class="profile-pic">            
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'poppins', 'sans-serif';
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url('/images/help2.jpg');
}

.profilebox {
    background: pink;
    text-align: center;
}
```

> I'm expecting background-image to work
> also i've used iconify for icons by giving link in  idk how to give it tho(i did it by watching yt). tell me how to do it and i've used unicons, is there naything else that can be used? how?

[this is how i've saved my files and folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64DS6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.container {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
background: url('../images/help2.jpg');
}
```

If you want to use Iconify.
Add this to HTML head

```
<script src="https://code.iconify.design/1/1.0.7/iconify.min.js"></script>
```

Then add icons to where you want like this.

```
<span class="iconify" data-icon="bi:alarm" data-inline="false"></span>
```